# template shows markup and not the page when combining context and forms

Tags: html, django, templates, django-templates, jinja2

I am fairly new to Django. I am trying to display a dictionary and form on the same page. However, it only vies the Html markup and not the actual page. Here is my code:

home/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from recruit.forms import RecruitForm


articles = [
{
    'author': 'Glenn',
    'title':'title 1',
    'content': 'first content',
    'date_posted': 'January 12'
},
{
    'author': 'batman',
    'title':'title 2',
    'content': 'second content',
    'date_posted': 'January 12'
},
{
    'author': 'batgirl',
    'title':'title 3',
    'content': ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas ratione 
       eaque nam totam! Labore consectetur nostrum dicta magnam ex expedita facilis  
       illum odit quibusdam vitae?',
    'date_posted': 'January 12'
}
]

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
  form = RecruitForm()
  context = {
    'articles': articles
}
return render(request, 'home/index.html', context, {'form':form})
```

recruit/forms.py:

```
 from django import forms
 from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
 from .models import Recruit

 class RecruitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = PhoneNumberField()

 class Meta:
    model = Recruit
    fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'city', 'contact_preference']
    widgets = {'contact_preference': forms.RadioSelect }
```

When I don't pass context the entire page renders. The same with form. I know how to validate forms, I just wanted to make this question as generic as possible. So either I can pass form or context but never both. When I do pass both I get my html markup and not document. By markup I mean the actual .html markup so the <!doctype>  ... any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass two objects to the template, you make a dictionary with two *entries*, so:

```
def index(request):
    form = RecruitForm()
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'form':form, 'articles': articles})
```

So you do not pass two dictionaries. The fourth parameter of the [**`render(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) is the `content_type`, not some extra context.

Comment: @WillemVanOnseem Thank you that works. You answered so fast I can't accept it yet. Whenever the time passes I will update. Thank you again.